# Is there any efficient way to count the occurrence of a regex in String object?

Tags: java

is there any efficient standard java library except String's split method that can help in counting the occurance of a given regex pattern in a given String object

Guys please throw some comments on below approach:

```
String s = "AA---AA---AA";
String[] temp = s.split("AA");
int count = temp.length - 1;
```

Comment: `Pattern` and `Matcher`...

Comment: you will still need a loop to tell the count, there is no direct method that can tell me the direct count of the regex occurence

Comment: No, it is not. Create your own library instead.

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way is to use a loop.  The standard library doesn't provide a method to do this.

Something like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
int count = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    count++;
}
```

The approach of using `String.split(separator)` is probably<sup>1</sup> less efficient, because it entails creating an array containing the string segments.  There is certainly no sound reason to think that the computational complexity of `split` is different to the approach with the loop.

---

<sup>1 - I haven't bothered to measure this.  If this is something that matters to you, you should construct a benchmark ...</sup>

Comment: have added another approach in question details, which one appears to have lower time complexity ??

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class RegexCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Test---Test---Test";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Test");
        Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
            count++;

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Output:
`3`